# Java Object Assignment

Tags: java, object, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment

I am new to Java and I have some questions in mind regarding object assignment. For instance,

```
Test t1 = new Test();
Test t2 = t1;
t1.i=1;
```

Assuming variable `i` is defined inside Test class, am I right to assume both t1 and t2 point to the same object where the modification `t1.i=1` affects both `t1` and `t2`? Actually I tested it out and seems like I was right. However when I try the same thing on `String`, the modification happens only on one side where the other side is unaffected. What is the reason behind this?

Edit: The case I tried with String.

```
String s1 = "0";
String s2 = s1;          
s1 = "1";
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

I realise my mistake by testing the cases on String since it is immutable. The situation where I thought `s1="1"` modify the string is in fact returning the reference of "1" to the s1. Nevertheless, my question remains. Does `Test t2 = t1;` cause both t2 and t1 point to the same object or each now have their own objects? Does this situation applies on all objects on Java?

Comment: What do you mean under 'try same thing on String'? There are no methods in String object to modify the string itself. Please read documentation carefully.

Comment: If you post the code of the test you're doing on String, we can be more specific on what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are right, but Strings are a special case; they are immutable and act like primitives in this case.

@newacct

I quote http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html :

> Note: The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a
>   String object cannot be         changed. The String class has a number
>   of methods, some of which will be discussed below, that     appear to
>   modify strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really
>   do is create     and return a new string that contains the result of
>   the operation.

This is what makes strings a special case. If you don't know this, you might expect the methods discussed in the quote not to return new strings, wich would lead to unexpected results.

@user1238193

Considering your following question: "Does Test t2 = t1; cause both t2 and t1 point to the same object or each now have their own objects? Does this situation applies on all objects on Java?"

t1 and t2 will point to the same object. This is true for any java object (immutable objects included)

Comment: There are no "special cases". Assignment to a reference of any type changes the object it points to, without affecting the object it used to point to.

Comment: Strings are a special case; they are objects, but they are immutable, meaning if you try to change them by for example String.replace you'll get a new object instead of the same object mutated.

Comment: No, `String` simply happens to not have any method that changes it. "try to change them" does not make sense; you cannot "try" to do something that doesn't exist. `String.replace` gives you a new object -- what's your point? That is what its documentation says it will do. `Integer` and many other classes are immutable. You can trivially write a class that is immutable, by making fields private and providing no methods to change its fields. And in any case, mutability is irrelevant to the question, which originally was about changing a field on `Test`, but there are no public fields on `String`

Comment: and then what do you do with the String pool, all classes have something like that ?

Comment: the String interning pool is completely irrelevant to this question or mutability. Any class may or may not have an interning pool like String

Answer (score 8):

You are right with your first assumption. With the following line of code:

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

you create a new Test object, and in the same time you create a Test reference named t1 to refer to it.

At the second line of the code you posted:

```
Test t2 = t1;
```

You are actually creating another Test reference, and you assign it to refer to the same object that t1 refers to.

So `t1.i = 1;` will affect `t2.i` for it is the same object after all.

As for the Strings, Strings are immutable and can not be modified after instantiated.

Regarding your edit:

```
String s1 = "0";
String s2 = s1;          
s1 = "1";
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

They will print different results, because when you actually say

```
s1 = "1";
```

you are actually binding s1 to another String object, but s2 will still be refering to the object with value "0".

Answer (score 5):

You are doing completely different things in the two cases. In the first case, with `t1.i = 1;`, you are modifying the object pointed to by `t1`. In the second case, with `t1 = "1";`, you are changing the reference to point to another object (similar to when you did `t2 = t1;`.

If you do the same thing to `Test` that you did in the second case, you would get the same result (assuming `Test` has a constructor that takes an integer):

```
Test t1 = new Test(5);
Test t2 = t1;          
t2 = new Test(1); // Here we are assigning to the variable, just like your 2nd example
System.out.println(t1);
System.out.println(t2);
```

People mention that `String` is immutable. But that is irrelevant and there is no concept of "mutability" in the language and there is no difference between how "mutable" and "immutable" classes work. We informally say a class is "immutable" if it happens to not have any fields you can set or any methods that can change its internal content. Such is the case with `String`. But a mutable class would work the exact same way if you simply do not do anything to mutate it.

Comment: Before downvoting and commenting on other answers, please kindly bother to see the question edit history. That'll give you a hint as to why many answers,saying the same thing, were upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You are absolutely right, as both t1 and t2 refering to same object, any chane in the object state will affect to both.

String is an immutable object. So it cannot be modified at all. [see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) for more info on immutable object in java.

Comment: That doesn't explain the problem. The same thing is true of `Test`: `Test s1 = new Test(2);
Test s2 = s1;          
s1 = new Test(1);`

Answer (score 2):

[String objects are immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

---

**EDIT**

*Does `Test t2 = t1;` cause both t2 and t1 point to the same object or each now have their own objects?*

Yes. Although `t2` is a new reference, but it will point to the same object, because you told it to do so. Create a new reference `t2` of type `Test` and let it point to the same object which `t1` is pointing at.

But, when you do this with `String`s and then do something like `s1 = "1" ;` you are making s1 point to another String object. You can think of it in terms `s1 = new String(1);`.

Comment: That doesn't explain the problem. The same thing is true of `Test`: `Test s1 = new Test(2);
Test s2 = s1;          
s1 = new Test(1);`

Comment: @newacct The OP edited the post later on. Initial post was answerable with these few words only. I'll edit my post now. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Even before the edit, "String is immutable" is not the correct answer. He said "when I tried the same thing on String"; the answer should be "What you said is impossible. It is impossible to do the same thing to String"

Answer (score 1):

String are object like any other. So any variable you assign them refer to the very same instance of the object, like you are doing with your test object.

But keep in mind that String have no field you can set like you do on Test, so you basically cannot do the same test, so there is no way to port your code from Test object to String object.

You get opposite behaviour using primitive types, such long,int etc.
They are assigned to variables "by value", so if you do

```
int t1 = 12;
int t2 = t1;
t1=15;
```

t2 still has value 12

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder as an example would be a litter bit clearer. Following example shows the object assignment just using the reference instead of the value.

{
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

```
    str.append("GFG");

    StringBuilder str1 = str;

    str.append("tail");
    // output: str1 = GFGtail str = GFGtail
    System.out.println("str1 = " + str1.toString() + " str = " + str.toString());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because java uses the concept of string literal. Suppose there are 5 reference variables, all refers to one object "0".If one reference variable changes the value of the object, it will be affected to all the reference variables. That is why string objects are immutable in java.